# Sending data from mobile app to Android Wear delay

Tags: android, wear-os, data-synchronization, android-wear-data-api

I'm trying to sync data between a settings app and a watch face and I'm having no luck. I've tried using a googleApiClient with listeners & onDataChanged and DataMaps, but there is a huge delay on the wear device to receive the data. (I'm talking like 5 minutes or more from being sent on from the mobile).

I've also tried to use Teleport Library for Wearable and I can confirm it works on the mobile side, but I receive nothing on the wear side.

Is there typically a huge delay with sync setting options? What's the best way to communicate between mobile and wear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Play Services 8.3, data synchronization using DataApi is batched up and done with a certain frequency which means synchronization of your data can be delayed up to 30 minutes. If you need immediate sync, you need to make sure your request is set as [urgent](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/PutDataMapRequest.html#setUrgent()).

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion! Is there a better way to sync between mobile and wear? I just want to turn on / off features on the watchface...

Comment: Another option is to send messages, using MessageApi but that doesn't have the resiliency of DataApi in the sense that it requires a connectivity at the time that message is send (unlike DataApi that syncs data when connectivity is restored). I believe for transferring settings, DataApi is a pretty good choice.

Comment: This works great! I was exactly looking for this. The lag in transferring information is sometimes acceptable but in most cases you want it to be over there right away - at least I would think that.