# Data duplication when syncing to wearable

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm trying to sync data from my phone (API 24) to an Android Wear watch (API 25).  Using [this example code](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html), I'm able to send data items successfully, however when I run the code in a loop, the data items are duplicating on the watch. It doesn't duplicate if I set a breakpoint in the loop and step through it.

As a test, I created a button that executes the sync code and if I press the button quickly, the items are duplicated but not if I pause between each button press.

I've tried using `SystemClock.sleep()` to pause the loop up to 5 seconds.  That is unreliable because some items duplicate, while others do not.

This code is an upgrade from `Wearable.DataApi`, which is deprecated, but the old code worked fine with no duplication.

```
    PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create("/import");
    dataMap.getDataMap().putString("title", "Title 1");
    PutDataRequest request = dataMap.asPutDataRequest();

    final Task<DataItem> task = Wearable.getDataClient(this).putDataItem(request);

    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataItem>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataItem dataItem) {

        }
    });

    task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
```

UPDATE:

For a test, I ran this code.  The result is that only the second data item is transferred to the watch.  If I comment out `putDataItem` for the second test 2, then the first test is displayed.  Putting `SystemClock.sleep` between them still results in only the second data item being transferred.

```
    final PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create("/import");
    dataMap.getDataMap().putString("title", "title1");
    dataMap.getDataMap().putString("rss_url", "http://wwww.test1.com");
    dataMap.getDataMap().putLong("time", new Date().getTime());
    final PutDataRequest request = dataMap.asPutDataRequest();

    Wearable.getDataClient(this).putDataItem(request);

    final PutDataMapRequest dataMap2 = PutDataMapRequest.create("/import");
    dataMap2.getDataMap().putString("title", "title2");
    dataMap2.getDataMap().putString("rss_url", "http://wwww.test2.com");
    dataMap2.getDataMap().putLong("time", new Date().getTime());
    final PutDataRequest request2 = dataMap2.asPutDataRequest();

    Wearable.getDataClient(this).putDataItem(request2);
```

UPDATE 2:

There is something seriously wrong with sending data back-to-back with the `com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable` class.  Any attempt to send data automatically, more then once, causes duplicates on the watch.

Going to submit a bug request to Google and hopefully it will be addressed in five years.

Bug submitted [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74357894), please star if you are experiencing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702376/sending-data-from-mobile-app-to-android-wear-delay

Comment: No, there is no delay, it's instant.  I've also tried setting the `urgent` property but still same results.